Can this form of Maa Laxmi Photo be kept and worshipped in home?
[Please be kind with your replies]
I was suggested by multiple Vastu Experts to keep a Photo of Maa Laxmi in the SE region of the house. I wanted a comparatively modern and beautiful image of Maa Lakshmi, and I found this absolutely beautiful image on the web. However, I found that this photo more accurately represents Maa Kamalatmika (one of the 10 Mahavidyas) - the tantric form of Ma Laxmi (I may be wrong here, correct me if wrong) or Maa Gajlakshmi.
I wanted to know that if this image is of Maa Kamalatmika, can her framed photo be kept and worshipped in home? I am asking because I have heard that Maa's Mahavidya Tantric Form needs special attention when being worshipped or even being kept at home.
I hope everyone understood my point. Please let me know.


Yes ..where is the problem in worshipping it in home?
